# Split an img element into four equal sized smaller img elements using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, split

I am trying to figure out how to take a given `img` element and, using Javascript, split that `img` into four equal sized tiles. That is, the upper-left quadrant of the original image would become its own `img` element, as the same with the other three quadrants. However, I am at a loss as to how I could do this. Could somebody offer a starting point or explain how/if this could be done? Would it have to be brute pixel manipulation?

Comment: What are you doing with the resulting images?  Are you just displaying them?

Comment: Currently, yes. I will do stuff with them later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the best solution here would be to use a canvas. The only caveat being that the original image must either be served locally or served via CORS. The steps to complete this solution would be to:

1. Select the image, or set the source of the image via javascript (if it is not displayed)
2. Onload of the image, create 4 canvases each 1/4 the size of the image
3. Using drawImage, draw each quarter of the image to each small canvas
4. Get each image source of each canvas (canvas.toDataUrl)
5. Create new image elements and set their source to each of new sources

The entire solution can be viewed on the linked codepen example.

[codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iLdCf)

Comment: My solution could be refactored of course, it is just an example of how to crop the image into 4 smaller images using canvas.

Comment: Why is only one quadrant showing though? I understand the code, but only the upper right corner shows. They all seem to be appending.

Comment: That is not happening for me; this is the javascript I have that displays the images as well http://pastie.org/8629349

Comment: It worked when I opened the codepen in Chrome, not Safari. Excellent. Thanks for the assist.

Comment: But why isnt it working on Safari and some other browsers? Canvas is not supported or what?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this in jQuery:

```
<div id="img">
    <img src="myimage.png" alt="" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" />
</div>

<script>
var imgSrc = $("#img img").attr("src");

for(var i=0; i<4; i++)
    $("#img").append($("<div></div>").attr("src", imgSrc).css({ width: (imgWidth / 4), height: (imgHeight / 4) }));
</script>
```

Comment: I believe the goal was to create new images, by cropping the original image into quarters.